# AsyncHttpClient and org.apache.http.client fails on SSL site while standard Android method works well

Tags: android, ssl, https, android-async-http

There was recently certificate change on staging servers of my app. The server passes Qualys SSL test with grade A- ("The server does not support Forward Secrecy with the reference browsers. Grade reduced to A-") so I should be able to connect via https **without adding any certs to my app, keystore or whatever.** Indeed, the standard Android connection method works well (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).

The problem is, I am using [android-async-http](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) all over the code, which uses org.apache.http.client. And that returns `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate` when I connect to the site!

I can't really change the connection method in current circumstances. I'd like to stay with android-async-http and connect to my site **without bypassing the SSL security**.

Any tips? Some additional settings to android-async-http? Or maybe altering android-async-http source code would help?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a same problem 6 months back.

I think you will be able to solve it by :

1. MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory
2. Then u need to use this Class where you are creating an instace of HTTPClient and pass some parameters...

I think the link below would be helpful. If it doesn't help then i can share concrete code later...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13812958/1386533

Comment: well, but your solution bypasess the SSL security, right? I explicitly stated (in bold) that I don't want to bypass it, I want stupid apache to recognize that the certificate is valid just like all web browsers on Android and standard Android method for downloading stuff over the web do.

Comment: no it does not by pass it.... u do not need to implement allow all certificate !!!